# MD5 says the checksum is correct but still "Check finished: errors found in 2 files"

Tags: boot, usb, checksums

I'm attempting to dual boot windows 8.1 and ubuntu but I can't quite seem to create a USB boot drive without errors.

Twice now I have downloaded ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64 from the official website, twice have the file's checksums been cross-referenced by winmd5sum with the md5 hash here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes, twice have I created a USB boot drive with Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.4, and twice have I checked for defects with the result being "Check finished: errors found in 2 files!"

What's going wrong?

Comment: Can you boot from the USB key? If yes, I wouldn't worry about the errors

Comment: _Maybe_ the checksum program is checking for _several_ files at the same time. So the image you downloaded passes OK, but the other 2 files you didn't download don't pass.

Comment: Realistically, what are the odds of this causing an issue? I mean, did you guys check for errors prior to installing? I nearly clicked install, just because checking for errors seemed like a waste of time, and I imagine there are quite a few people who just went ahead without checking and things worked out fine for them.

Comment: I know this is from 2014 July, but I would still really like to know the answer to @cancub's comment question. :/

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible reasons for corruption.  It can be that your USB stick is bad (e.g. there are some which lie about their size and corrupt the data at the end).  It can be that your image writing software is bad.  It seems (from various pages on the internet) that Universal USB installer can incorrectly write files to the USB stick so that was probably the explanation in this case.  What you should do is find different software for writing the image and never use Universal-USB-Installer again.

You should *never* install from a corrupt image because it's completely possible for things to work now and then later you end up with data corruption or worse.  If it does work that's just luck.