# Ubuntu 14.04.4 – "Check for defects" – "Errors found in 2 files"

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation, usb, checksums

#### First off...

First off, I've already searched Ask Ubuntu and found multiple other questions<sup>[[1]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498794/md5-says-the-checksum-is-correct-but-still-check-finished-errors-found-in-2-fi#) [[2]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707806/ubuntu-check-for-defects-errors-found-in-1-file) [[3]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674338/which-files-are-the-faulty-ones-when-checking-defects) [[4]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/547332/can-an-integrity-check-be-run-against-a-usb-boot-disk/547369#547369)</sup>, but a) most of them don't fully fit my circumstances, and b) the ones that do haven't been answered fully, if at all. So don't mark this as a duplicate because it's not one.

Now, then...

---

#### The Question

I booted my computer to USB and it gave me the option to check the disk for defects. I did so, but it returned an error—on two separate occasions—saying "Errors found in 2 files".

#### The Details

- I tried this whole thing twice, both from the same ISO file<sup>∗</sup> and using Universal USB Installer, but across 2 USB flash drives.
- Both times I tested the MD5 hash using [the official hash released by Ubuntu](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.4/MD5SUMS). Both times, the [MD5 & SHA Checksum Utility](https://raylin.wordpress.com/downloads/md5-sha-1-checksum-utility/) cleared it as matching.

---

#### Specs

- *Make & Model*: Lenovo G50
- *Operating System*: Windows 10 Home 64-Bit
- *Prospective Distro*: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS Desktop 64-Bit
- *Flash Drive (1<sup>st</sup> Attempt)*: Silicon Power USB 3.0 16 GB
- *Flash Drive (2<sup>nd</sup> Attempt)*: SanDisk Cruzer Blade USB 2.0 8 GB

---

---

<sup>∗</sup> Thanks to 100 kb/s WiFi speeds, it takes 2–3 hours just to download the dang ISO file; so obviously I'm not gonna do it more than once unless I absolutely have to...

Comment: Have you tried using a different program to create the LiveUSB?  I personally use [unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/)

Comment: Universal USB Installer is the program specifically mentioned by the [official Ubuntu help page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) on the matter.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Universal USB installer.

If checksums are correct, there must be a problem with the live usb creator.

After that I used Unetbootin (on Windows 7) and there weren't any errors anymore.

https://unetbootin.github.io/

Comment: I'm reformatting my flash drive again; then I'll be trying UNetbootin, per your and @user4901968's suggestion. I'll re-comment once I do to update you all.

Comment: UNetbootin worked for me. Universal USB Installer always wrote corrupt files.

Comment: UNetbootin failed for me, trying to get Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo P50

Answer (score 0):

In my case I also had this issue during `Integrity check` / `Check for defects` – `Errors found in 2 files`.

One of them was `grub` (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2-signed/+bug/1617721).

I didn't fix it, but workaround was to connect to the Internet and check `Download updates during installation`.