# the grub-efi-amd64-signed package failed to install into target error

Tags: system-installation

I'm installing Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot beside Windows 10. I got the following error:

```
the grub-efi-amd64-signed package failed to install into target
```

And the machine doesn't boot. Note that my computer doesn't support UEFI.

Comment: Have you created an EFI partition?

Comment: It must support UEFI, otherwise it would not be trying to install the UEFI version of grub. What brand/model system? If within last 5 years, it will be UEFI hardware. And vendors are required to install Windows in UEFI boot mode, but users can install in the now 35 year old BIOS with MBR partitions.  Post this above from Ubuntu installer in live mode, terminal: `sudo parted -l`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use a Windows 10 USB stick to fix your partitions(known as "Fix the MBR" or Startup Repair). Make sure you have an EFI partition working with no problems. There are several tutorials on Google to **clean** and **create a new EFI partition from the W10 USB CMD promtp**.
Then, boot the Ubuntu USB, and select manual installation:

[image]

Create the followings partitions:  **/**, **SWAP**, **/home**
Click to Install Now, and apply the changes.

Long time ago I had this issue, googling and doing this solved my problem.
Hope to get good news.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to fix partitions (known as "Fix the MBR" or Startup Repair), but it didn't help.

The issue itself was in grub package (`grub-efi-amd64-signed_1.66.14+2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.14+linuxmi.deb` 
[for details check here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747940/ubuntu-14-04-4-check-for-defects-errors-found-in-2-files/1194854#1194854)).

Answer (score 0):

I've a similar problem on Asus laptop. I used a DVD bootable Ubuntu and got this error for several times. The problem is mainly raised from the bios setting. In my case, I went to my bios setting, boot section, delete "UEFI: Ubuntu" from the choices. Then I chose the other Ubuntu (for legacy mode) boot option and placed in the first priority. 
Finally, I succeeded to install the Ubuntu 18.04.3 along with win 10.